# Prove that $(n!)^2 ≥ n^n$ using mathematical induction

Tags: induction

### 1°

$n_0=1$

$(1!)^2 \ge 1^1$

$1\ge1$

### 2°

$k \ge n_0$

assumption: $$(k!)^2 \ge k^k$$

and for k+1: $$((k+1)!)^2 \ge (k+1)^{k+1}$$

I also noticed that: $$((k+1)!)^2 = (k!)^2 * (k+1)^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your steps, we are just required to prove

$$k^k \geq (k+1)^{k-1} \Leftrightarrow k^{k-1} \cdot k \geq (k+1)^{k-1}\Leftrightarrow (\frac{k}{k+1})^{k-1} \geq \frac{1}{k}$$

Using [Bernouli's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), we have

$$(\frac{k}{k+1})^{k-1}=(1-\frac{1}{k+1})^{k-1} \geq 1-\frac{k-1}{k+1}=\frac{2}{k+1}$$

So, we are just left to prove $$\frac{2}{k+1} \geq \frac{1}{k}\Rightarrow 2k \geq (k+1) \Rightarrow k \geq 1$$ which is obvious.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont really understand this way. From where did you get: $(\frac{k}{k+1})^{k-1} \geq \frac{1}{k}$

Comment: I had a day off and just went back to it. Still i try to come up with an idea how did you get this part. On my own I came to: $n >= ((n+1)/n)^(n-1)

Comment: @Overkillus What's the confusion? $n \geq (\frac{n+1}{n})^{n-1} \Rightarrow (\frac{n}{n+1})^{n-1} \geq \frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 1):

A direct approach may be simpler: We have 
$$(n!)^2=\prod_{k=1}^nk\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n}(n+1-k)=\prod_{k=1}^nk(n+1-k)\ge\prod_{k=1}^nn  $$
because
$k(n+1-k)=-k^2+(n+1)k$ is a "downward" quadratic, hence is minimal at the boundary places $k=1$ and $k=n$.